# set execution permission to files deployed from windows to lambda using serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using serveless to deploy lambda function, I need to add an executable bin file but when it is uploaded I don't have executable permissions, also I can't change permissions after deployed, the only thing I can do is to move the file to /tmp and there change the permissions, it works ok but adds a lot of overhead because I have to move the files on every Invoke becasue /tmp is ephemeral.

I know there is a known issue that windows&linux files permission are different, so if you zip a file on windows and unzip it on a linux machines you will have problem with permission, especialy with execution, and that happens when serverless deploys the files.

¿Anyone have a better workaround for this? (rather than "deploy from a windows machine")